# JavaScript + E4X: how to test if an element has text nodes?

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, text, e4x

In E4X, I know how to test if an element has a particular attribute, but how do I test if an element has text nodes?

```
js>x = <foo><bar /><baz attr1="123" /><quux>some random text</quux></foo>
<foo>
  <bar/>
  <baz attr1="123"/>
  <quux>some random text</quux>
</foo>
js>'@attr1' in x.baz
true
js>'@attr1' in x.quux
false
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [hasSimpleContent](http://wso2.org/project/mashup/0.2/docs/e4xquickstart.html) method for elements without attributes or children:

```
x.quux.hasSimpleContent()
```

Use a RegExp to remove the tags and whitespace to aggregate the text nodes:

```
Boolean(x.toString().replace(/<.*?\>/g,"").replace(/\W/g,"").length)
```